# How to create Html View Using Php & Html

Tags: php, html, arrays

What  I  Need

- i need to implement create the rows & columns like ex:
- url of image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/YViEQ.png.

  1. row [type].
  2. row [comment].
  3. row[price].

Array Structure As Follows

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array(
            [type] => [metadata] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [0] => [1] =>
                )

            )

        )

        [1] => Array(
            [type] => General Public Tickets Adult[metadata] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [0] => (Working Days)[1] => 50
                )

                [1] => Array(
                    [0] => (Saturday / Sunday / Holiday)[1] => 80
                )

            )

        )

        [2] => Array(
            [type] => General Public Tickets Child: (5 - 12 years of age)[metadata] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [0] => Working Days[1] => 30
                )

                [1] => Array(
                    [0] => (Saturday / Sunday / Holiday)[1] => 50
                )

            )

        )

        [3] => Array(
            [type] => Business Tickets[metadata] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [0] => Per Person Per Day(November 14 - 18, 2014)[1] => 400
                )

                [1] => Array(
                    [0] => multiple entry(validity: November 14 - 27, 2014)[1] => 1500
                )

            )

        )

    )
```

html code

```
    <h2>Entry Fee</h2>

            <table class="tb not-mobile" width="800" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">

            <tr>
            <td width="30%" rowspan="2">General Public Tickets  Adult</td>
            <td width="58%">(Working Days)</td>
            <td width="12%" class="aligncenter">50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>(Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)</td>
            <td class="aligncenter">80</td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">General Public Tickets  Child : (5 - 12 years of age) </td>
            <td>Working Days</td>
            <td class="aligncenter">30</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>(Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)</td>
            <td class="aligncenter">50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> Business Tickets </td>
            <td>Per Person Per Day (November 14-18, 2014)</td>
            <td class="aligncenter">40</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>multiple entry   (validity : November 14-27, 2014)</td>
            <td class="aligncenter">1500</td>
            </tr>

            </table>
```

code i have tried

```
print '<table width="800" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';
foreach($result as $place => $task) {
    //print_r($task);

    $i = 0;
    print "<tr> 
        <td width='30%' rowspan=".$place."> 
            ".$task['type']." 
        </td>
        <td width='58%'>
            ".$task['type']."
        </td> 
        <td width='12%' class='aligncenter'>
             ".$task['type']." 
        </td>
    </tr>";

    foreach($task as $thingToDo) {
        print_r($thingToDo);
        $i++;
        if ($i == 2) {
            print "<tr>";
            print "<td>".$thingToDo.
            "</td>";
            print "<td class='aligncenter'>".$thingToDo.
            "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            $i = 0;
        } else {
            print "<tr>";
            print "<td>".$thingToDo[$i].
            "</td>";
            print "<td class='aligncenter'>".$thingToDo.
            "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
        }


    }
}
print " </table>";
```

- problem im facing html is not comming appropiate as per image.

Comment: What is wrong ? Show us what you have, so we don't have to run the code to figure out.

Comment: Can you please post the generated HTML?

Comment: i have updated my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could nest another table inside that. Example:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <?php foreach($array as $val1): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val1['type']; ?>
        <td ><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <?php foreach($val1['metadata'] as $metadata): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $metadata[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $metadata[1]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?></table></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MYXoxB)